# Elastic Search not working for basic authentication in cluster mode

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, elasticsearch, .net-core, nest

We have a elastic search service running in two nodes as a cluster. Without authentication, it works fine. Pointing to a single node also works fine. But, when we run with `ConnectionPool`, it is throwing below error. Tried with `SniffingConnectionPool` and `StaticConnectionPool`. Both did not help. We use `Elasticsearch.Net` and `Nest` version 7.0.

```
# FailureReason: MaxRetriesReached while attempting PUT on http://ely-es-2-perf.westindia.cloudapp.azure.com:9200/user_profile/_doc/2e18d331-9734-4915-b7cd-4893a270b52c
# Audit trail of this API call:
# Request:
<Request stream not captured or already read to completion by serializer. Set DisableDirectStreaming() on ConnectionSettings to force it to be set on the response.>
# Response:
<Response stream not captured or already read to completion by serializer. Set DisableDirectStreaming() on ConnectionSettings to force it to be set on the response.>
# Inner Exception: One or more errors occurred. (Failed to ping the specified node.) (Failed to ping the specified node.)
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Failed to ping the specified node.) (Failed to ping the specified node.)
 ---> Elasticsearch.Net.PipelineException: Failed to ping the specified node.
 ---> Elasticsearch.Net.PipelineException: An error occurred trying to read the response from the specified node.
   at Elasticsearch.Net.RequestPipeline.PingAsync(Node node, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Elasticsearch.Net.RequestPipeline.PingAsync(Node node, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Elasticsearch.Net.Transport`1.PingAsync(IRequestPipeline pipeline, Node node, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Elasticsearch.Net.Transport`1.PingAsync(IRequestPipeline pipeline, Node node, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Elasticsearch.Net.Transport`1.RequestAsync[TResponse](HttpMethod method, String path, CancellationToken cancellationToken, PostData data, IRequestParameters requestParameters)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
 ---> (Inner Exception #1) Elasticsearch.Net.PipelineException: Failed to ping the specified node.
 ---> Elasticsearch.Net.PipelineException: An error occurred trying to read the response from the specified node.
   at Elasticsearch.Net.RequestPipeline.PingAsync(Node node, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Elasticsearch.Net.RequestPipeline.PingAsync(Node node, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Elasticsearch.Net.Transport`1.PingAsync(IRequestPipeline pipeline, Node node, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Elasticsearch.Net.Transport`1.PingAsync(IRequestPipeline pipeline, Node node, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Elasticsearch.Net.Transport`1.RequestAsync[TResponse](HttpMethod method, String path, CancellationToken cancellationToken, PostData data, IRequestParameters requestParameters)<---

# Exception:
Elasticsearch.Net.ElasticsearchClientException: Maximum number of retries reached, failed over to all the known alive nodes before failing. Call: Status code 504 from: HEAD /
 ---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Failed to ping the specified node.) (Failed to ping the specified node.)
 ---> Elasticsearch.Net.PipelineException: Failed to ping the specified node.
 ---> Elasticsearch.Net.PipelineException: An error occurred trying to read the response from the specified node.
   at Elasticsearch.Net.RequestPipeline.PingAsync(Node node, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Elasticsearch.Net.RequestPipeline.PingAsync(Node node, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Elasticsearch.Net.Transport`1.PingAsync(IRequestPipeline pipeline, Node node, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Elasticsearch.Net.Transport`1.PingAsync(IRequestPipeline pipeline, Node node, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Elasticsearch.Net.Transport`1.RequestAsync[TResponse](HttpMethod method, String path, CancellationToken cancellationToken, PostData data, IRequestParameters requestParameters)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
 ---> (Inner Exception #1) Elasticsearch.Net.PipelineException: Failed to ping the specified node.
 ---> Elasticsearch.Net.PipelineException: An error occurred trying to read the response from the specified node.
   at Elasticsearch.Net.RequestPipeline.PingAsync(Node node, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Elasticsearch.Net.RequestPipeline.PingAsync(Node node, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Elasticsearch.Net.Transport`1.PingAsync(IRequestPipeline pipeline, Node node, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Elasticsearch.Net.Transport`1.PingAsync(IRequestPipeline pipeline, Node node, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Elasticsearch.Net.Transport`1.RequestAsync[TResponse](HttpMethod method, String path, CancellationToken cancellationToken, PostData data, IRequestParameters requestParameters)<---

   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

Our Code

```
var uris = new[]
{
    new Uri(_configuration["ElasticAPI1"]),
    new Uri(_configuration["ElasticAPI2"])
};
var connectionPool = new SniffingConnectionPool(uris);
ConnectionSettings settings = new ConnectionSettings(connectionPool).BasicAuthentication(_configuration["ES.Name"], _configuration["ES.Password"]);
ElasticClient client = new ElasticClient(settings);
settings.DefaultIndex(indexname);

//Add data
var response = await client.IndexAsync<Model>(model, null).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

**Edit:**
Same code worked before without setting up authentication. Worked fine with `SniffingConnectionPool`.

Comment: A 504 Gateway timeout response looks suspicious. Looks like you’re running in Azure; do you have a load balancer in front of the cluster e.g. Application Gateway? Do the nodes have public IP addresses? Also it looks like it’s still running over HTTP - I **strongly** recommend that certificates are configured for the HTTP layer and use HTTPS to connect

Comment: Thanks @RussCam for your suggestions. You are right. We have Azure application gateway. Nodes have public DNS. And we tried with HTTPS to connect and still the same error.

Comment: with a loadbalancer in front of the cluster, neither `SniffingConnectionPool` or `StaticConnectionPool` should be used - use `SingleNodeConnectionPool` with the address of the load balancer.

Answer (score 0):

The issue happens when the client tries to "ping" the nodes with the simplest request to check if it is available. so the nodes that are protected by authentication will respond 401 and then you will have issues on your end.

I solve this issue by adding .DisablePing() into the ConnectionSettings.

After that you will need to handle the errors in case the node is down, but the request was sent to it.

I found also that the user you are using should have cluster:monitor permission

for more info -> https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/issues/3870